# FIND {query} with special characters failing with ampersand

Tags: query, sosl, escape

`FIND {tim/?jacob}` parses perfectly fine when running the query.

`FIND {tim/&jacob}` gives the following error:

> line 1:10 mismatched character '&' expecting '}'`

what am I doing wrong?

According to [Salesforce Developer Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm), the ampersand is possible to escape, as it is included in this list:

> Escaping special characters `& | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ '`

**EDIT:**

I used the wrong slash, which explains the above error.
When changing to `FIND {tim\&jacob}` as per the documentation, I get this parsing error.

> Invalid string literal 'FIND {tim\&jacob} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING '. Illegal character sequence '\&' in string literal.

When changing to `FIND {tim\\&jacob}`, I do not get an error, but the query is parsed as `FIND {tim\&jacob}` when I return it to me, and this returns 0 results.

Comment: When I executed the FIND {tim/&jacob} in Dev console I am getting the [{"message":"","errorCode":"MALFORMED_SEARCH"}]

Comment: / isn't the escape character, \ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by ignoring the documentation.

`Find \' Tim&Jacob \'` actually did the trick, with no escapes.

Since  my string is actually held in a variable, here is my final code.

```
searchStr = 'Tim&Jacob';
String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr + '\'';
```

Answer (score 1):

That's some poorly written documentation.

Rewritten in an attempt to clarify:

> Special characters that must be escaped using the escape character (`\`):
>   `& | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ '`
>
> Examples of escaping special characters:
>
> - Right Brace: `Find {\}}`
> - Asterisk: `Find {\*}`
> - Question Mark: `Find {\?}`
> - Single Quote: `Find {\'}`
> - Double Quote: `Find {\"}`

Comment: Using the proper escape character unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the backslash "\" to escape the special/reserved characters (you are using the slash "/" in your find sosl instead of "\"....).
P.s. in some cases you may need to do a double escape "\".

Comment: I edited my question - after trying with "\\",  I get a final result of `{tim\&jacob}`